# Meteor Iron-Router: Wait for Subscription sequential

Tags: meteor, iron-router, subscription

I have the following route defined in my iron-router:

```
    this.route("/example/:id", {
    name: "example",
    template: "example",
    action: function () {
        this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('sub1', this.params.id));
        this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('sub2', <<data of sub1 needed here>>));

        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render();
        } else {
            this.render('Loading');
        }
    }
});
```

I want to wait for sub1 and sub2 before rendering my actual template. The problem is that I need a piece of data which is part of the result of sub1 for the sub2 subscription.

How can I wait sequential for subscriptions? So that I can split the wait in two steps and wait for my first subscription to be finished. Then start the second subscription and then set this.ready() to render the template?

A workaround that I thought of was to use Reactive-Vars for the subscriptions and dont use .wait and .ready which is provided by iron-router. But I would like to use a more convenient solution provided by iron-router or Meteor itself. Do you know a better solution for this?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can't you just create sub3 that takes the same parameter as sub1 and returns the data of sub1 and sub2?

Comment: i did not know that a publish function can return results of two different collections? is that really true?

Comment: yes just return an array https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish

Comment: funny thing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Publish Composite Package:

If the second subscription is reactively dependent on certain fields from the first dataset -- and if there will be a many-to-many "join" association, it might be worth looking into [`reywood:publish-composite`](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package:

It provides a clean and easy way to manage associated subscriptions for collections with hierarchical relations.

***Publication:***

```
Meteor.publishComposite('compositeSub', function(id) {
    return {
        find: function() {
            // return all documents from FirstCollection filtered by 'this.params.id' passed to subscription
            return FirstCollection.find({ _id: id });
        },
        children: [
            find: function(item) {
                // return data from second collection filtered by using reference of each item's _id from results of first subscription
                // you can also use any other field from 'item' as reference here, as per your database relations
                return SecondCollection.find({ itemId: item._id });
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

***Subscription:***

Then you can just subscribe in the router using:

```
Meteor.subscribe('compositeSub', this.params.id);
```

### Router hooks:

As a suggestion, hooks in iron-router are really useful, as they take care of a lot of things for you. So why not use the [`waitOn`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-waiton-option) hook that manages `this.wait` and `loading` states neatly?

```
this.route('/example/:id', {
  name: "example",
  template: "example",
  // this template will be rendered until the subscriptions are ready
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',

  waitOn: function () {
    // return one handle, a function, or an array
    return Meteor.subscribe('compositeSub', this.params.id);  
    // FYI, this can also return an array of subscriptions
  },

  action: function () {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

You can use the `configure` option to add a template for loading event:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

#### Note regarding the comment in question:

If both subscriptions only depend on the same `id` parameter passed to it, you can use the following, as mentioned by *@abj27* in the comment above -- however, this does not seem to be the case, going by your example:

***Publication:***

```
Meteor.publish("subOneAndTwo", function (exampleId) {
  check(exampleId, String);
  return [
    FirstCollection.find({ _id: exampleId });
    SecondCollection.find({ firstId: exampleId })
  ];
});
```

***Subscription:***

```
Meteor.subscribe('subOneAndTwo', this.params.id);
```

So just check what you need and use a solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager

With this package, you can assign a subscription to a variable. Then, you can check that variable's ready state. I just got this working... after years of trying to understand.

Here is my code snippet that works, but oddly I had to wrap it in a 1ms timeout to work...

```
Router.route('/activity/:activityId', function (params) {

```
var params = this.params;

setTimeout(function(){

    var thePage = window.location.href.split("/");; 
    window.thePage = thePage[4];

    dbSubscriptionActivites.clear();
    window.thisDbSubscriptionActivites = "";
    window.thisDbSubscriptionActivites = dbSubscriptionActivites.subscribe("activityByPage", window.thePage);


    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        if(window.thisDbSubscriptionActivites.ready()) {

            dbSubscriptionComments.clear();
            window.thisDbSubscriptionComments = "";
            window.thisDbSubscriptionComments = dbSubscriptionComments.subscribe('fetchComments', "activity", Activities.findOne({})._id);

            BlazeLayout.render("activity"); 
            $('body').removeClass("shards-app-promo-page--1");

        }
    });

},1); // Must wait for DOM?
```

});
```

Examine: window.thisDbSubscriptionActivites = dbSubscriptionActivites.subscribe("activityByPage", window.thePage);

I'm setting as a window variable, but you could do a const mySub = ...

Then, you check that in the autorun function later.

You can see there is where I am doing subscriptions.

I suppose I really should move the BlazeLayout render in to another .ready() check for the comments.